# remote Alfresco webservice for alfresco 4.2c

Tags: java, web-services, alfresco, remote-access

I am trying to access file placed in alfresco 4.2c folder. I used following code to access remote alfresco. I am using Netbeans and GlassFish Server 4.1.1.Am i missing some jar files or doing any mistake in configuration/code.

Code:
    package JavaPackage;

```
import org.alfresco.webservice.util.AuthenticationUtils;
import org.alfresco.webservice.util.WebServiceFactory;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import static java.lang.System.out;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletOutputStream;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.alfresco.webservice.authentication.AuthenticationFault;

import org.alfresco.webservice.content.Content;
import org.alfresco.webservice.content.ContentServiceSoapBindingStub;
import org.alfresco.webservice.repository.UpdateResult;
import org.alfresco.webservice.types.CML;
import org.alfresco.webservice.types.CMLCreate;
import org.alfresco.webservice.types.ContentFormat;
import org.alfresco.webservice.types.NamedValue;
import org.alfresco.webservice.types.ParentReference;
import org.alfresco.webservice.types.Predicate;
import org.alfresco.webservice.types.Reference;
import org.alfresco.webservice.types.Store;
import org.alfresco.webservice.util.AuthenticationUtils;
import org.alfresco.webservice.util.Constants;
import org.alfresco.webservice.util.ContentUtils;
import org.alfresco.webservice.util.Utils;
import org.alfresco.webservice.util.WebServiceFactory;
/**
 *
 * @author Mamoona-PC
 */
public class BackClass {
/** Admin user name and password used to connect to the repository */
    protected static final String USERNAME = "admin";
    protected static final String PASSWORD = "admin";

    /** The store used throughout the samples */
    protected static final Store STORE = new Store(Constants.WORKSPACE_STORE, "SpacesStore");

    protected static final Reference SAMPLE_FOLDER = new Reference(STORE, null, "/app:company_home/cm:News"); 

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
    {
       WebServiceFactory.setEndpointAddress("http://192.168.10.18/alfresco/api");
        AuthenticationUtils.startSession(USERNAME, PASSWORD);
        try
        {
            // Check to see if the sample folder has already been created or not
            WebServiceFactory.getRepositoryService().get(new Predicate(new Reference[]{SAMPLE_FOLDER}, STORE, null));
            ParentReference parentRef = new ParentReference();
            parentRef.setStore(STORE);
            parentRef.setUuid(SAMPLE_FOLDER.getUuid());
            parentRef.setPath(SAMPLE_FOLDER.getPath());
            parentRef.setAssociationType(Constants.ASSOC_CONTAINS);
            parentRef.setChildName(Constants.ASSOC_CONTAINS);

            NamedValue[] properties2 = new NamedValue[]{Utils.createNamedValue(Constants.PROP_NAME, "empty.txt")};
            CMLCreate create2 = new CMLCreate();
            create2.setParent(parentRef);
            create2.setProperty(properties2);
            create2.setType(Constants.TYPE_CONTENT);   

            CML cml2 = new CML();
            cml2.setCreate(new CMLCreate[] {create2});

              UpdateResult[] result = WebServiceFactory.getRepositoryService().update(cml2);

            Reference contentNode = result[0].getDestination();
            ContentFormat format = new ContentFormat(Constants.MIMETYPE_TEXT_PLAIN, "UTF-8");
            byte[] content = "This is some test content provided by the Alfresco development team!".getBytes();
            Content content1 = WebServiceFactory.getContentService().write(contentNode,
                  Constants.PROP_CONTENT, content, format);

        }
        catch (Exception e){
              e.printStackTrace();
              e.getMessage();
        }
    } 
}
```

Libraries:

[image]

Error:

```
run:
AxisFault
 faultCode: {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Server.userException
 faultSubcode: 
 faultString: org.apache.axis.ConfigurationException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.ws.axis.security.WSDoAllSender
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.ws.axis.security.WSDoAllSender
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.apache.axis.utils.ClassUtils$2.run(ClassUtils.java:187)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.apache.axis.utils.ClassUtils.loadClass(ClassUtils.java:160)
    at org.apache.axis.utils.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:100)
    at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDDeployableItem.getJavaClass(WSDDDeployableItem.java:353)
    at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDDeployableItem.makeNewInstance(WSDDDeployableItem.java:295)
    at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDDeployableItem.getNewInstance(WSDDDeployableItem.java:274)
    at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDDeployableItem.getInstance(WSDDDeployableItem.java:260)
    at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDChain.makeNewInstance(WSDDChain.java:125)
    at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDDeployableItem.getNewInstance(WSDDDeployableItem.java:274)
    at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDDeployableItem.getInstance(WSDDDeployableItem.java:260)
    at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDDeployment.getGlobalRequest(WSDDDeployment.java:473)
    at org.apache.axis.configuration.FileProvider.getGlobalRequest(FileProvider.java:269)
    at org.apache.axis.AxisEngine.getGlobalRequest(AxisEngine.java:365)
    at org.apache.axis.client.AxisClient.invoke(AxisClient.java:126)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invokeEngine(Call.java:2784)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2767)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2443)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2366)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:1812)
    at org.alfresco.webservice.repository.RepositoryServiceSoapBindingStub.get(RepositoryServiceSoapBindingStub.java:1078)
    at JavaPackage.BackClass.main(BackClass.java:60)

org.apache.axis.ConfigurationException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.ws.axis.security.WSDoAllSender
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.ws.axis.security.WSDoAllSender
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.apache.axis.utils.ClassUtils$2.run(ClassUtils.java:187)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.apache.axis.utils.ClassUtils.loadClass(ClassUtils.java:160)
    at org.apache.axis.utils.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:100)
    at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDDeployableItem.getJavaClass(WSDDDeployableItem.java:353)
    at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDDeployableItem.makeNewInstance(WSDDDeployableItem.java:295)
    at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDDeployableItem.getNewInstance(WSDDDeployableItem.java:274)
    at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDDeployableItem.getInstance(WSDDDeployableItem.java:260)
    at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDChain.makeNewInstance(WSDDChain.java:125)
    at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDDeployableItem.getNewInstance(WSDDDeployableItem.java:274)
    at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDDeployableItem.getInstance(WSDDDeployableItem.java:260)
    at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDDeployment.getGlobalRequest(WSDDDeployment.java:473)
    at org.apache.axis.configuration.FileProvider.getGlobalRequest(FileProvider.java:269)
    at org.apache.axis.AxisEngine.getGlobalRequest(AxisEngine.java:365)
    at org.apache.axis.client.AxisClient.invoke(AxisClient.java:126)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invokeEngine(Call.java:2784)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2767)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2443)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2366)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:1812)
    at org.alfresco.webservice.repository.RepositoryServiceSoapBindingStub.get(RepositoryServiceSoapBindingStub.java:1078)
    at JavaPackage.BackClass.main(BackClass.java:60)

    at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDDeployableItem.makeNewInstance(WSDDDeployableItem.java:297)
    at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDDeployableItem.getNewInstance(WSDDDeployableItem.java:274)
    at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDDeployableItem.getInstance(WSDDDeployableItem.java:260)
    at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDChain.makeNewInstance(WSDDChain.java:125)
    at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDDeployableItem.getNewInstance(WSDDDeployableItem.java:274)
    at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDDeployableItem.getInstance(WSDDDeployableItem.java:260)
    at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDDeployment.getGlobalRequest(WSDDDeployment.java:473)
    at org.apache.axis.configuration.FileProvider.getGlobalRequest(FileProvider.java:269)
    at org.apache.axis.AxisEngine.getGlobalRequest(AxisEngine.java:365)
    at org.apache.axis.client.AxisClient.invoke(AxisClient.java:126)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invokeEngine(Call.java:2784)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2767)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2443)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2366)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:1812)
    at org.alfresco.webservice.repository.RepositoryServiceSoapBindingStub.get(RepositoryServiceSoapBindingStub.java:1078)
    at JavaPackage.BackClass.main(BackClass.java:60)

 faultActor: 
 faultNode: 
 faultDetail: 
    {http://xml.apache.org/axis/}stackTrace:org.apache.axis.ConfigurationException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.ws.axis.security.WSDoAllSender
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.ws.axis.security.WSDoAllSender
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.apache.axis.utils.ClassUtils$2.run(ClassUtils.java:187)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.apache.axis.utils.ClassUtils.loadClass(ClassUtils.java:160)
    at org.apache.axis.utils.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:100)
    at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDDeployableItem.getJavaClass(WSDDDeployableItem.java:353)
    at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDDeployableItem.makeNewInstance(WSDDDeployableItem.java:295)
    at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDDeployableItem.getNewInstance(WSDDDeployableItem.java:274)
    at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDDeployableItem.getInstance(WSDDDeployableItem.java:260)
    at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDChain.makeNewInstance(WSDDChain.java:125)
    at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDDeployableItem.getNewInstance(WSDDDeployableItem.java:274)
    at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDDeployableItem.getInstance(WSDDDeployableItem.java:260)
    at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDDeployment.getGlobalRequest(WSDDDeployment.java:473)
    at org.apache.axis.configuration.FileProvider.getGlobalRequest(FileProvider.java:269)
    at org.apache.axis.AxisEngine.getGlobalRequest(AxisEngine.java:365)
    at org.apache.axis.client.AxisClient.invoke(AxisClient.java:126)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invokeEngine(Call.java:2784)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2767)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2443)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2366)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:1812)
    at org.alfresco.webservice.repository.RepositoryServiceSoapBindingStub.get(RepositoryServiceSoapBindingStub.java:1078)
    at JavaPackage.BackClass.main(BackClass.java:60)

org.apache.axis.ConfigurationException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.ws.axis.security.WSDoAllSender
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.ws.axis.security.WSDoAllSender
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.apache.axis.utils.ClassUtils$2.run(ClassUtils.java:187)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.apache.axis.utils.ClassUtils.loadClass(ClassUtils.java:160)
    at org.apache.axis.utils.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:100)
    at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDDeployableItem.getJavaClass(WSDDDeployableItem.java:353)
    at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDDeployableItem.makeNewInstance(WSDDDeployableItem.java:295)
    at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDDeployableItem.getNewInstance(WSDDDeployableItem.java:274)
    at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDDeployableItem.getInstance(WSDDDeployableItem.java:260)
    at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDChain.makeNewInstance(WSDDChain.java:125)
    at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDDeployableItem.getNewInstance(WSDDDeployableItem.java:274)
    at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDDeployableItem.getInstance(WSDDDeployableItem.java:260)
    at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDDeployment.getGlobalRequest(WSDDDeployment.java:473)
    at org.apache.axis.configuration.FileProvider.getGlobalRequest(FileProvider.java:269)
    at org.apache.axis.AxisEngine.getGlobalRequest(AxisEngine.java:365)
    at org.apache.axis.client.AxisClient.invoke(AxisClient.java:126)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invokeEngine(Call.java:2784)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2767)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2443)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2366)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:1812)
    at org.alfresco.webservice.repository.RepositoryServiceSoapBindingStub.get(RepositoryServiceSoapBindingStub.java:1078)
    at JavaPackage.BackClass.main(BackClass.java:60)

    at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDDeployableItem.makeNewInstance(WSDDDeployableItem.java:297)
    at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDDeployableItem.getNewInstance(WSDDDeployableItem.java:274)
    at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDDeployableItem.getInstance(WSDDDeployableItem.java:260)
    at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDChain.makeNewInstance(WSDDChain.java:125)
    at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDDeployableItem.getNewInstance(WSDDDeployableItem.java:274)
    at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDDeployableItem.getInstance(WSDDDeployableItem.java:260)
    at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDDeployment.getGlobalRequest(WSDDDeployment.java:473)
    at org.apache.axis.configuration.FileProvider.getGlobalRequest(FileProvider.java:269)
    at org.apache.axis.AxisEngine.getGlobalRequest(AxisEngine.java:365)
    at org.apache.axis.client.AxisClient.invoke(AxisClient.java:126)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invokeEngine(Call.java:2784)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2767)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2443)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2366)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:1812)
    at org.alfresco.webservice.repository.RepositoryServiceSoapBindingStub.get(RepositoryServiceSoapBindingStub.java:1078)
    at JavaPackage.BackClass.main(BackClass.java:60)

    at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDDeployableItem.makeNewInstance(WSDDDeployableItem.java:297)
    at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDDeployableItem.getNewInstance(WSDDDeployableItem.java:274)
    at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDDeployableItem.getInstance(WSDDDeployableItem.java:260)
    at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDChain.makeNewInstance(WSDDChain.java:125)
    at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDDeployableItem.getNewInstance(WSDDDeployableItem.java:274)
    at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDDeployableItem.getInstance(WSDDDeployableItem.java:260)
    at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDDeployment.getGlobalRequest(WSDDDeployment.java:473)
    at org.apache.axis.configuration.FileProvider.getGlobalRequest(FileProvider.java:269)
    at org.apache.axis.AxisEngine.getGlobalRequest(AxisEngine.java:365)
    at org.apache.axis.client.AxisClient.invoke(AxisClient.java:126)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invokeEngine(Call.java:2784)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2767)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2443)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2366)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:1812)
    at org.alfresco.webservice.repository.RepositoryServiceSoapBindingStub.get(RepositoryServiceSoapBindingStub.java:1078)
    at JavaPackage.BackClass.main(BackClass.java:60)

    {http://xml.apache.org/axis/}hostname:Mamoona-PC-PC

org.apache.axis.ConfigurationException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.ws.axis.security.WSDoAllSender
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.ws.axis.security.WSDoAllSender
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.apache.axis.utils.ClassUtils$2.run(ClassUtils.java:187)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.apache.axis.utils.ClassUtils.loadClass(ClassUtils.java:160)
    at org.apache.axis.utils.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:100)
    at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDDeployableItem.getJavaClass(WSDDDeployableItem.java:353)
    at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDDeployableItem.makeNewInstance(WSDDDeployableItem.java:295)
    at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDDeployableItem.getNewInstance(WSDDDeployableItem.java:274)
    at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDDeployableItem.getInstance(WSDDDeployableItem.java:260)
    at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDChain.makeNewInstance(WSDDChain.java:125)
    at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDDeployableItem.getNewInstance(WSDDDeployableItem.java:274)
    at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDDeployableItem.getInstance(WSDDDeployableItem.java:260)
    at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDDeployment.getGlobalRequest(WSDDDeployment.java:473)
    at org.apache.axis.configuration.FileProvider.getGlobalRequest(FileProvider.java:269)
    at org.apache.axis.AxisEngine.getGlobalRequest(AxisEngine.java:365)
    at org.apache.axis.client.AxisClient.invoke(AxisClient.java:126)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invokeEngine(Call.java:2784)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2767)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2443)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2366)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:1812)
    at org.alfresco.webservice.repository.RepositoryServiceSoapBindingStub.get(RepositoryServiceSoapBindingStub.java:1078)
    at JavaPackage.BackClass.main(BackClass.java:60)

org.apache.axis.ConfigurationException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.ws.axis.security.WSDoAllSender
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.ws.axis.security.WSDoAllSender
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.apache.axis.utils.ClassUtils$2.run(ClassUtils.java:187)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.apache.axis.utils.ClassUtils.loadClass(ClassUtils.java:160)
    at org.apache.axis.utils.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:100)
    at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDDeployableItem.getJavaClass(WSDDDeployableItem.java:353)
    at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDDeployableItem.makeNewInstance(WSDDDeployableItem.java:295)
    at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDDeployableItem.getNewInstance(WSDDDeployableItem.java:274)
    at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDDeployableItem.getInstance(WSDDDeployableItem.java:260)
    at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDChain.makeNewInstance(WSDDChain.java:125)
    at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDDeployableItem.getNewInstance(WSDDDeployableItem.java:274)
    at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDDeployableItem.getInstance(WSDDDeployableItem.java:260)
    at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDDeployment.getGlobalRequest(WSDDDeployment.java:473)
    at org.apache.axis.configuration.FileProvider.getGlobalRequest(FileProvider.java:269)
    at org.apache.axis.AxisEngine.getGlobalRequest(AxisEngine.java:365)
    at org.apache.axis.client.AxisClient.invoke(AxisClient.java:126)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invokeEngine(Call.java:2784)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2767)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2443)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2366)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:1812)
    at org.alfresco.webservice.repository.RepositoryServiceSoapBindingStub.get(RepositoryServiceSoapBindingStub.java:1078)
    at JavaPackage.BackClass.main(BackClass.java:60)

    at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDDeployableItem.makeNewInstance(WSDDDeployableItem.java:297)
    at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDDeployableItem.getNewInstance(WSDDDeployableItem.java:274)
    at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDDeployableItem.getInstance(WSDDDeployableItem.java:260)
    at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDChain.makeNewInstance(WSDDChain.java:125)
    at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDDeployableItem.getNewInstance(WSDDDeployableItem.java:274)
    at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDDeployableItem.getInstance(WSDDDeployableItem.java:260)
    at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDDeployment.getGlobalRequest(WSDDDeployment.java:473)
    at org.apache.axis.configuration.FileProvider.getGlobalRequest(FileProvider.java:269)
    at org.apache.axis.AxisEngine.getGlobalRequest(AxisEngine.java:365)
    at org.apache.axis.client.AxisClient.invoke(AxisClient.java:126)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invokeEngine(Call.java:2784)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2767)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2443)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2366)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:1812)
    at org.alfresco.webservice.repository.RepositoryServiceSoapBindingStub.get(RepositoryServiceSoapBindingStub.java:1078)
    at JavaPackage.BackClass.main(BackClass.java:60)

    at org.apache.axis.AxisFault.makeFault(AxisFault.java:101)
    at org.apache.axis.client.AxisClient.invoke(AxisClient.java:216)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invokeEngine(Call.java:2784)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2767)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2443)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2366)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:1812)
    at org.alfresco.webservice.repository.RepositoryServiceSoapBindingStub.get(RepositoryServiceSoapBindingStub.java:1078)
    at JavaPackage.BackClass.main(BackClass.java:60)
Caused by: org.apache.axis.ConfigurationException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.ws.axis.security.WSDoAllSender
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.ws.axis.security.WSDoAllSender
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.apache.axis.utils.ClassUtils$2.run(ClassUtils.java:187)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.apache.axis.utils.ClassUtils.loadClass(ClassUtils.java:160)
    at org.apache.axis.utils.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:100)
    at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDDeployableItem.getJavaClass(WSDDDeployableItem.java:353)
    at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDDeployableItem.makeNewInstance(WSDDDeployableItem.java:295)
    at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDDeployableItem.getNewInstance(WSDDDeployableItem.java:274)
    at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDDeployableItem.getInstance(WSDDDeployableItem.java:260)
    at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDChain.makeNewInstance(WSDDChain.java:125)
    at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDDeployableItem.getNewInstance(WSDDDeployableItem.java:274)
    at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDDeployableItem.getInstance(WSDDDeployableItem.java:260)
    at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDDeployment.getGlobalRequest(WSDDDeployment.java:473)
    at org.apache.axis.configuration.FileProvider.getGlobalRequest(FileProvider.java:269)
    at org.apache.axis.AxisEngine.getGlobalRequest(AxisEngine.java:365)
    at org.apache.axis.client.AxisClient.invoke(AxisClient.java:126)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invokeEngine(Call.java:2784)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2767)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2443)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2366)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:1812)
    at org.alfresco.webservice.repository.RepositoryServiceSoapBindingStub.get(RepositoryServiceSoapBindingStub.java:1078)
    at JavaPackage.BackClass.main(BackClass.java:60)

org.apache.axis.ConfigurationException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.ws.axis.security.WSDoAllSender
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.ws.axis.security.WSDoAllSender
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.apache.axis.utils.ClassUtils$2.run(ClassUtils.java:187)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.apache.axis.utils.ClassUtils.loadClass(ClassUtils.java:160)
    at org.apache.axis.utils.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:100)
    at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDDeployableItem.getJavaClass(WSDDDeployableItem.java:353)
    at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDDeployableItem.makeNewInstance(WSDDDeployableItem.java:295)
    at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDDeployableItem.getNewInstance(WSDDDeployableItem.java:274)
    at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDDeployableItem.getInstance(WSDDDeployableItem.java:260)
    at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDChain.makeNewInstance(WSDDChain.java:125)
    at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDDeployableItem.getNewInstance(WSDDDeployableItem.java:274)
    at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDDeployableItem.getInstance(WSDDDeployableItem.java:260)
    at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDDeployment.getGlobalRequest(WSDDDeployment.java:473)
    at org.apache.axis.configuration.FileProvider.getGlobalRequest(FileProvider.java:269)
    at org.apache.axis.AxisEngine.getGlobalRequest(AxisEngine.java:365)
    at org.apache.axis.client.AxisClient.invoke(AxisClient.java:126)
    ... 7 more
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 1 second)
```

Comment: Why are you messing around with the old webservices stuff? Why aren't you following Alfresco best-practice, and using either CMIS or the Public API?

Comment: then do you know any query method to download file from alfresco using path of folder.

Answer (score 1):

You probably have some sort of version conflict between your Axis JAR, your WSS4J JAR, and your WSDL4J JAR. Double-check the docs for those JARs to make sure the versions you've selected are meant to work with each other.

With that said, I agree with @Gagravarr that the Alfresco native Web Services API should be avoided. It was eventually deprecated and subsequently removed not too long after the release you are using.

A much easier way to work with content in Alfresco is via CMIS. [This page](https://chemistry.apache.org/docs/cmis-samples/samples/retrieve-objects/index.html) shows examples for grabbing objects by their object ID or by path. And [this page](https://chemistry.apache.org/docs/cmis-samples/samples/content/index.html) talks about working with content streams.